# "Picking up" header on Y position javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to **Toggle** my Navbar's `position` style property between **Fixed** and **Relative** based on **Y scroll** position.
**Here's an example:**
http://www.granapstudio.com/

Here's my JavaScript. I tried **switching classes**

```js
$(function() { 
  var header = $(".clearHeader"); 
  $(window).scroll(function() { 
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    if (scroll >= 800) { 
      header.removeClass('clearHeader').addClass("darkHeader"); 
    } 
    else { 
      header.removeClass("darkHeader").addClass('clearHeader'); 
    } 
  }); 
});
```

**The problem:** This solution doesn't work when I *zoom in* or *zoom out*.

Comment: _but problem is with scaling page_, what problem is that exactly?

Comment: In my javascript code:
 `<script>
$(function() {
    var header = $(".clearHeader");
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    
        if (scroll >= 800) {
            header.removeClass('clearHeader').addClass("darkHeader");
        } else {
            header.removeClass("darkHeader").addClass('clearHeader');
        }
    });
});
</script>`
When i zoom in or zoom out scroll become smaller so if i scroll 10 times it apper on half of main section.

Comment: @pHenomen Please add relevant code as an edit, rather than in a comment. You also may want to have a fiddle/snippet so we can see exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek  Here is my example on codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezpBdd

You can try zoom in or zoom out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the example page provided is using a jquery plugin

https://github.com/garand/sticky

Comment: Hi @Sean , it would be great if you could add some details around this link. By details i meant some text, some excerpt from the readme file etc. This would help the people find your answer more useful and more upvotes :D

Answer (score 1):

Instead of testing if `scroll >= 800` 

use `scroll >= header.offset().top`

this way you get the top position of a given element.